# Input_Path_Not_Canonicalized - PathTravesal Vulnerability in checkmarx

Tags: path, checkmarx, secure-coding, path-traversal

I am facing path traversal vulnerability while analyzing code through checkmarx. I am fetching path with below code:

```
String path  = System.getenv(variableName);
```

and *"path"* variable value is traversing through many functions and finally used in one function with below code snippet:

```
File file = new File(path);
```

Checkmarx is marking it as medium severity vulnerability.

Please help.
How to resolve it to make it compatible with checkmarx?

Answer (score 2):

Other answers that I believe Checkmarx will accept as sanitizers include **Path.normalize**:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

String path  = System.getenv(variableName);
Path p = Paths.get(path);
Path normalizedPath = p.normalize();
path = new File(normalizedPath.toString());
```

or the **FilenameUtils.normalize** method:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

String path  = System.getenv(variableName);
File file = new File(FilenameUtils.normalize(path));
```

Comment: giving you a +1! your first answer worked for me! although you might need to make some minor corrections, the last line returns a `File`, not a `String`, so it should be `File file = new File(normalizedPath.toString());`. Otherwise all else is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate canonicalized path by calling `File.getCanonicalPath()`.

In your case:

```
String path  = System.getenv(variableName);
path = new File(path).getCanonicalPath();
```

For more information read [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath())